# 3D Character Development

Tags: 3d, movement, character

First and for most. I do have a fair amount of experience programming. I have experience with many programming languages and I have taken a few courses in computer science. I have development some basic 2D games from scratch (Tron, Pong and Tic-Tac-Toe). However, I am a noob when it comes to 3D games design. What I wanted to do was to create a basic character and to implement some movements on the character in a blank space. Now there are numerous software out there and I can't wrap my head around all the information. Could someone please set me in the right direction with what software I should learn (e.g. Autodesk, 3DS Max, I dont even know if these are the right ones).

As a side note I also wanted to develop some advanced character movements, kinda like the ones you see in the Assassins Creed series. I was very curious as to how this is done and the software involved. So again could someone please point me in the right direction here as well.

Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: you don't code movements, which is in your case which you explained what you are looking for is an animation. you just play (call a function of a class of a 3d engine with a parameter saying which animation you want to play like walk,run,jump,slide, kick etc) the animation which is created by the 3d artist using a 3d software like maya, 3dsmax etc. If you are looking to crate 3d character and create movements (which is technically called animation) then you asked in wrong place. if you question is about coding then try unity3d, go to tutorials to get introduction to 3d world

Comment: Where to get started, and which technology to use questions are off topic for the site. Please read the [FAQ] to learn what types of questions to ask here and to find a list of sites that are more suitable for those types of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you listed 'Autodesk' as example but Autodesk is not one software it is the company that make Autodesk Revit, Autodesk AutoCad, Autodesk Maya, Autodesk 3ds MAX studio and Autodesk Inventor. But since you can do animation with said softwares, you will be limited in what you can do in a free trial unless you are ready to buy them...

I will suggest [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) because it is free and opensource. If you make something and later wish to publish it as a game, you can. No strings attached. It has also been used in many animation movies through out and is quiet famous in the industry as such.

The best part is, it also comes with it's built-in game engine which you can use to create your very own 3D game.

There are also a lot of good tutorials to get your feet wet.

Comment: The blender game engine isn't all that good, and I haven't seen anyone using it. There are plenty of free graphics and game engines out there like Unity, Unreal, Cryengine, etc.

Comment: @rootlocus I realize that there are way better game engines available, but that does not what he is asking. My answer was not aimmed over particular engine but his question in general.